# Changing the pytorch weight decay value prevents the validation loss and training loss from decreasing

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, regularized

I'm trying to regularize my model with pytorch optimizer using the `weight_decay` parameter. When the `weight_decay` value is equal to 0 (which is the default vallue), the *training loss* and *validation loss* decrease. But when I try setting the `weight_decay` to different values (eg. 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1...) the *validation loss* and *training loss* remain the same during all the epochs (0.70). What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried real low value ? Since 1e-4 is actually pretty high. Something like 1e-7 or 1e-8 ? You should start from very low and increase it step by step, monitoring both the final loss and the norm of the weight matrices to measure the effect quantitatively.

Comment: @milembar I've tried to minimize it and it didn't work.

Comment: Whould be great if you could give us a minimal reproducible example, because otherwise it is just a guessing game.